# Building a multi-step webforms - One table DB or multiple tables

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm in the process of building a multi-step application form that has 7 sections such as 'your details', 'your financial circumstances', 'previous history', etc.

I would like to save the users input at the end of each section - i.e. on submit/continue - but I'm unsure whether to use one huge table (there are lots of fields!) or break the data down into multiple tables based on the sections.

I'm leaning towards the latter because it seems more logical and orderly, however I'm unsure how to link the tables so that the data will be linked to each user who fills out the form?

I've only worked on single page/table web forms in the past, one db with one table (example below) which collects data from a competition of some sort:

```
CREATE TABLE user_data ( 
id INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
firstName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
lastName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
postcode VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
telephoneNumber VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
emailAddress VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
dateTime TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP );
```

So this is a new area for me, any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

As you are using  master and details here, I am not sure how can you store all the information  in one big table. In this case, for one user there will be multiple history. That means you have to use one-to-many relationship in this case. You have not provided much detail. However, I would like to know how do you design you table schema using just one table.

Comment: I've updated my question a little bit for you Prabir.

You say 'for one user there will be multiple histories', but I don't understand how that would be, because each new person that fills in the webform would create a new entry in the database across all the tables, unless there were some sort of login system that I could attribute the user's to each completed webform?

This project will not use a login system, its basically just a multi-step webform.

I think I need to understand the relationships between tables in more detail.

Comment: What information can I provide you with to give you a better idea of what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Your user_data table is perfect. Now create a table "user_history" with user_id as foreign key.  This table can have additional column for "description" , "date" etc. In your case, you mentioned that you have no login mechanism. That means web page has no information about which user has logged-in. Then you should have some other mechanism  to  know user_id.  You can provide a search function for user.  Then  user selects a user and updates this user's information across all the tables.

Answer (score 1):

If you have collection data type in form (like table) you have two choice:

1. Create one to many tables for each collection type
2. Store data in software readable formate like json in text field of database.